# Android - Awesome Validation for password confirmation

Tags: java, android, validation

I am not able to validate the confirmed password in the edittext.

```
String regexPassword = "\\d{1}\\d{1}\\d{1}\\d{1}";
    String ConfirmregexPassword = MPIN.getText().toString().trim();
    awesomeValidation.addValidation(this, R.id.MPIN, regexPassword, R.string.MPINError);
    if (ConfirmMPIN.getText().toString().trim()!=MPIN.getText().toString().trim() ) {
        awesomeValidation.addValidation(this, R.id.ConfirmMPIN, ConfirmregexPassword, R.string.ConfirmMPIN);
        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Comment: use equals instead of =

Answer (score 1):

use .equals() method

```
 if ((ConfirmMPIN.getText().toString().trim()).equals((MPIN.getText().toString().trim()) )) {
            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "if", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "else", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

Comment: in this case it is not going to if condition

Comment: i have added !(not) in the begning of statement, remove ! from if statement

Comment: yes i saw that (not).. but  not working

Comment: check updated answer @anusha machavarapu

Answer (score 1):

when you have to compare two String you can use `String.equals()` method which is used to Compares this string to the specified object. The result is true if and only if the argument is not null and is a String object that represents the same sequence of characters as this object.

**try this**

```
 awesomeValidation.addValidation(this, R.id.ConfirmMPIN, ConfirmregexPassword, R.string.ConfirmMPIN);
```

**or try this**

```
if (ConfirmMPIN.getText().toString().trim().equals(MPIN.getText().toString().trim() )) {

    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Password Match", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }else{

   Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Not Matched", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
}
```

Comment: in this case it is not going to if condition

Comment: @anushamachavarapu check updated ans

Comment: OK but it is also not working

Comment: @anushamachavarapu can u explained in brief

Comment: @anushamachavarapu check updated ans

Comment: it is also not workimg

Comment: can your explain in brief